# Can we determine kafka broker health through any of the consumer JMX metrics?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, health-monitoring, broker

I want to monitor Kafka broker health with the help of Kafka Consumer JMX metrics. I am running a Kafka Consumer application which generates the JMX metrics. Is there any metrics which can tell us the Kafka broker health?

I know, we can monitor the broker health with the help of Broker metrics but I want to monitor with the help Consumer JMX metrics.

Please let me know if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: The consumer metrics essentially outlines the parameters for the Kafka Consumer and they give you a quantitative representation of some important internal parameters for the consumer only , there is no way to know about the Broker .

Comment: yeah, @SoumenMukherjee, agree on that but there are some metrics which looks like that it can help me out i.e. type_consumer-node-metrics. I am trying to explore it more but not reached to a positive conclusion yet. Btw, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "health". The consumer would only know a connection is made to the leader brokers, and status of authorization to its topics. It wouldn't know if a brokers disks were filling up, for example

Comment: @cricket_007 Here, health means whether the brokers are up or not. I just want to determine whether any of the broker is down.

Comment: Any of them, or just those holding data of the topic you're reading from?

Comment: In my case, we have 3 brokers and the partitions are distributed across the brokers so ideally, all the brokers are holding the data.